# Popup Text on a Select list in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

First, I thank you for reading my post,

As my title says it I need to create popups on an option select. 
I've searched in many jquery tutorials but they all talk about buttons or  tags to create popups.

But that really doesn't help cause here is the fact : all my selected tags are in an  tag which make the button and  tag of no use.

So I need that when someone, with his mouse, just hover the text present in the selected option, there's for each options a dialog box that appears with in it the description of the text hovered , so here's my code :

```
<select name ="soin" id="soin" size="5"> <!-- the second one, pseudo-dynamic -->
            <option value="">-----Select-----</option>
                <option value="Passage" class="Logistique" >Passage</option>
            <option value="PresenceDansUs" class="Logistique">Présence dans une US</option>
            <option value="Rangement" class="Logistique">Rangement</option>
            <option value="Medicarte" class="Logistique">Medicarte</option>
            <option value="ChercheMateriel" class="Logistique">Cherche du Matériel</option>
            <option value="Transfert" class="Logistique">Transfert d'un patient</option>
            <option value="Autre" class="Logistique">Autre</option>
...there are 50 more values...
        </option>
```

So for example if someone hover the mouse on "Passage" ,the first select value, a box appear with :"Passage is a  way across a specified location" and so on for the others.
Here is a little picture to help you to figure out the idea:
[image]

and then with the mouse on the option value
[image]

That "dialog box" was made with paint, so please don't tell me I did it xD

So I thank you for your concern because I'm too junior to make that sort of things in jquery .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might be looking for is the '`title`' attribute of the `<option>` tag -

```
<option value="Passage" title="Passage is a way across a specified location" class="Logistique" >Passage</option>
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cp6g8et/1/)

If you hover your mouse over the 'Passage' option, you will see the message as a small tooltip.

Comment: My god, it was so simple :o

Thank you V2solutions :)